# How to display email href link as bold based on status field value in visual force page

Tags: visualforce, email

We have custom emails section for the case object. I want to display the email subject hyper link as bold if email status is NEW. for all other status it should be in normal font. Could you please help me how to get this.
custom and Standard email section :
[image]

Below are my vf page subject related code lines :

```
<apex:column headerValue="Subject">
        <a herf="/{!items.id}" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="openDetailPage('{!items.id}', '{!items.Incoming}')" > {!items.subject} </a>

    </apex:column>

function openDetailPage(emailid, Incoming)
    {
        console.log(Incoming);
        statusForEmail = Incoming;
        salesforceSubTab = emailid;
        //var pages= "/"+emailid;            
        //window.open(pages,'_parent');
        sendpage2(emailid);
        subjectId = emailid;
     }

function sendpage2(emailId)
    { 
        var pages = "/"+emailId;
        //window.open(pages,'_parent');
        if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
            sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(openSubtab13);
        }else{

            var pages = "/"+emailId;
            window.open(pages,'_parent');
        }
        //'salesforce', openSuccess, 'salesforceTab');
    }

var openSubtab13 = function openSubtab13(result) {
           console.log(result);
           // var pages = "/"+emailId;
           var emailmsg = '';
           var subTab13 = salesforceSubTab;
        //Now that we have the primary tab ID, we can open a new subtab in it
           if(statusForEmail == false)
               {
               emailmsg = 'Outbound Email Message'
               }
           if(statusForEmail == true)
               {
                emailmsg = 'Inbound Email Message'
                }
        var primaryTabId = result.id;
       var pages= "/"+subjectId;   
        sforce.console.openSubtab(primaryTabId, pages, true, 
                                  emailmsg , null, openSuccess, subTab13);
    };
```

I tried to add style=" font-weight : bold;" rendered with condition on status but it is not working as expected.

This issue i have resolved with the below changes : instead of `<a href/>` i used `<apex:commandlink/>`

```
 <apex:commandLink action="/{!items.id}" style="cursor: pointer;font-weight: bold;" rendered="{!if(items.status == '0',true,false)}" onclick="openDetailPage('{!items.id}', '{!items.Incoming}')" value="{!items.subject}"/>
        <apex:commandLink action="/{!items.id}" style="cursor: pointer;" rendered="{!if(items.status == '0',false,true)}"  onclick="openDetailPage('{!items.id}', '{!items.Incoming}')" value="{!items.subject}"/>
```

Comment: Please include your code as text in the body of your question, not as a screenshot. To help the community help you, include the code you are using *now* and describe how it does not work.

Comment: Sure David will do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While playing around with the `rendered` attribute can work, that approach is a bit ham-fisted (i.e. I think there's a better way to do it).

The approach I would take here is probably to make use of the `class` attribute. Make a CSS class to add font-weight:bold, and then use a merge expression to determine whether or not to apply that class (or other CSS classes)

A bare-bones example:

```
<style>
    .boldText{
        font-weight:bold
    }
</style>

<!-- other markup here -->

<a href="" class="{!IF(item.isNew, 'boldText', ''}" />
```

Comment: Yes Derek, I faced some other issue while using in console application hence i applied the changes in < a href/> tag as below that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Derek, I faced some other issue while using rendered in console application hence i applied the changes in < a href/> tag as below that worked.

```
<a herf="/{!items.id}" style="{!if(items.status == '0','cursor: pointer;font-weight: bold;','cursor: pointer;')}" onclick="openDetailPage('{!items.id}', '{!items.Incoming}')" > {!items.subject} </a>
```